# Stressed of Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm an Android Developer, and I'm not a newbie, but I can't find any CLEAR information about developing games with Cocos2d-x.

My hardware is: a Lenovo computer with Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

I have found only tutorials that says how to compile the "HelloCpp" on your Android phone.

I have some questions:

1. What is the environment to WRITE the code? Xcode?
2. How can I run my games for looking a suddenly modify, only if I have a Mac? with Eclipse? Xcode?.
3. Being multi-platform, if I develop the whole game for iPhone, will be I able to compile it to Android?

and so, is that easy to "write and run" as I would do an Android app in Eclipse with ADT Plugin???

Sorry, I don't understand very much about this.

Comment: 1. You can write the code in any IDE. 2. I don't understand the question. 3. Naturally. - Last question is subjective, you can't compare two ways of development, everyone's experience is different, every tech has different pros and cons. - Generally speaking: yes, cocos2d-x isn't the easiest engine to get started with.

Comment: Hi @LearnCocos2D , thanks for your reply. I give an example of the second question: as Android developer, I'm not used to DEBUG my apps, but RUN. So, when I modify, for example, an "if sentence", I can re-run my application and I get a new app in my emulator/device. Can i do that with Cocos2D, Ubuntu and Eclipse?

Comment: Uhm, yes. That's pretty common for app development in general. I mean what else would you expect? It wouldn't make any sense if it were to ignore your code changes.